# Solution to the following set of equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

Is the solution to the following:

$$a^2+b^2=1$$
$$c^2+d^2=1$$
$$ad+bc=1$$

still $a=d=\cos z$, $c=-b=\sin z$, when $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: You must have $(a,b) = (c,d)$, so no.

Comment: No. However I don't know why not just say $a$ is arbitrary, $a=d$ and $b=c=\pm \sqrt{1-a^2}$...

Comment: @Asydot the reason I write in this way is that for the group $SO_2(\mathbb R)=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos z & -\sin z \\
\sin z & \cos z \\
\end{bmatrix}$, so I want to know what $SO_2(\mathbb C)$ looks like

Comment: The determinant equation should be $ad-bc=1$, not $ad+bc=1$.

Comment: Uh... I guess I'm late, but let me remind you that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad+bc)^2+(ac-bd)^2$, so that $ac-bd=0, ac=bd, \frac {a} {b} = \frac {d} {c}$.